# Calling Objective-C function from Javascript & Anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I've set up the bridge between Objective-C and JavaScript numerous times.

So, anything like this works fine:

```
objc.callSomeFunc();
objc.callAnotherOne_("param");
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is : Call an Objective-C function, passing an anonymous function as a parameter. In a few words, call an Objective-C function and WHEN it's over call back a custom, user-defined Javascript function. Like this:

```
objc.callSomeFunc_WithCallback_("param", function() { echo "I got called back" });
```

---

An "easy" way would be to pass the "callback" call as pure js (perhaps a string format), which Objective-C would simply have to execute, like:

```
objc.callSomeFunc_WithCallback_("param", "myfunc('%@');");
myfunc(param)
{
}
```

And from my Objective-C code doing something like:

```
- (void)callSomeFunc:(NSString*)param WithCallback:(NSString*)callback
{
     // Do stuff
     NSString* callbackCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:callback,@"myparam"];
     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:callbackCommand];
}
```

---

So far so good. But is it the correct approach?

How would you do it?